# Download CRM 2011 VPC

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to download the CRM 5.0 VPC without the whole Customer Portal/Partner non sense.
If it's a demo vpc why should I have to cut through red tape.

All I'm looking to do is learn and try out some samples.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27822

Answer (score 0):

In the partnersource image, we have simply stopped the Sharepoint services, disabled the Sharepoint IIS site, stopped unrequired services like Analysis services and finally disabled all but 1 organization. It works fairly well. I don't there is a ready-made plain vanilla image available freely.